# dotenv/rails-now "Puma caught this error: Could not load the 'mysql' Active Record adapter."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dotenv

I am trying to use the [bkeepers/dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem in a new install of rails. I am using mariadb (`mysql2` adapter) which worked fine.

Once I install the dotenv gem, I get the following error whenever I try to run a test or make a request:

```
Puma caught this error: Could not load the 'mysql' Active Record adapter. Ensure that the adapter is spelled correctly in config/database.yml and that you've added the necessary adapter gem to your Gemfile. (LoadError)
/[...]/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.16.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require'
```

I don't even need to attempt to use the gem or env vars, just having it installed seems to be causing the issue. I have tried moving it earlier in the `Gemfile`, per the Github page, etc, to no avail. Removing the gem immediately fixes the issue.

I assume there is some loading detail I am misunderstanding. Here is the most recent ordering of the pertinent section of the `Gemfile`:

```
ruby "3.1.2"

gem 'dotenv-rails', require: 'dotenv/rails-now' # <= tried it below as well
gem "apipie-rails", "~> 1.2"
gem "bootsnap", require: false # Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'mysql2'
gem "puma", "~> 5.0" # Use the Puma web server [https://github.com/puma/puma]
gem "rails", "~> 7.0.7", ">= 7.0.7.2"
gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[ mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby ] # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: And by _"I don't even need to attempt to use the gem or env vars"_ you mean that [you don't have any of the `.env*` files](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#what-other-env-files-can-i-use) present in your project?

Comment: @smathy I have a `.env` file

Comment: Show us what's in it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a leftover value in my `.env` from using [dbmate](https://github.com/amacneil/dbmate)

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://user_name:password@localhost:3306/db_name"
```

Turns out Rails uses this incredibly generic env var:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/80592d6dc6c3d98ab26e4a8ab88462d6e6da87af/guides/source/configuring.md?plain=1#L2905
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/80592d6dc6c3d98ab26e4a8ab88462d6e6da87af/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake#L44
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/80592d6dc6c3d98ab26e4a8ab88462d6e6da87af/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L450

Thanks to @smathy for pointing me in the right direction.